# Facebook getloginurl redirect_uri with variable

Tags: php, facebook

I have a problem with facebook redirect_uri.

```
$params = array(
  'scope' => 'email,user_birthday,publish_actions',
  'redirect_uri' => 'https://apps.facebook.com/appname?kick_id=58'
);

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

Here is a problem that after authentication page facebook redirects to https://apps.facebook.com/appname not to https://apps.facebook.com/appname?kick_id=58
how to pass that variable ?kick_id=58 ?

P.S. I have tried and /?kick_id=58, but nothing happens. Have you any idea how to fix such thing?

Comment: Have you tried **Tamper Data** ? Maybe Facebook is redirecting you from `/appname?kick_id=58` to `/appname`

Comment: no /appname?kick_id=58 redirects to /appname/?kick_id=58. I tried that already. About that Temper Data how you can use it, because I found only a program

Comment: It's a plugin for firefox to track and edit GET & POST variables

Comment: well I need to do this in all browsers not only for firefox, because it will be public app, not only for me

Comment: Why don’t you just put the info you need into the session …?